# Django 1.5.4 unable to serve css on development server

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I tried have so many things but just cant serve css and image. I am trying to render a background image through css. The following is the code site

simple_emp_hr/

```
 |->hr_base/
 |      |-> views.py
 |      |-> templates/hr_base/homepage.html
 |      |-> static
 |            |->css/base.css
 |            |->images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg
 |
 |->simple_emp_hr/
         |->urls.py
         |->settings.py
```

The following is the view:

```
@csrf_protect
def index(request):
    print(request.GET)
    print(request.POST)
    template = loader.get_template('hr_base/homepage.html')
    c = Context()
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'user':request.user.username})
    str = template.render(c)
    response = str
    print(str)
    hres = HttpResponse()
    hres.write(response)
    return hres
```

The following is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hr_base/index$','hr_base.views.index'),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':         settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indices':True}),
)
```

The following is my settings.py:

```
# Django settings for simple_emp_hr project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

MANAGERS = ADMINS


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
"hr_base/static/hr_base/",
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'simple_emp_hr.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
"../simple_emp_hr/hr_base/templates/",
"../simple_emp_hr/emp_users/templates/",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'hr_base',
)
```

My css file has:

```
body {
    background-image: url ("images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg"); }
title {
    background-color: rgb(238,62,128);
    color: white; }
```

The following is homepage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Simple Employee HR : Solutions for the companies which are <em>simple</em></title>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Employee HR : Solutions for the companies which are <em>simple</em></h1>
    <hr />
    <h2 id="top">Who we are</h2>
    <hr />
    <a href="#top">top</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The print in view allows me to print the html rendered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Simple Employee HR : Solutions for the companies which are <em>simple</em></title>
    <link href="css/base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Employee HR : Solutions for the companies which are <em>simple</em></h1>
    <hr />
    <h2 id="top">Who we are</h2>
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
[17/Feb/2014 14:40:17] "GET /hr_base/index HTTP/1.1" 200 1455
[17/Feb/2014 14:40:17] "GET /hr_base/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3640
```

I never got the css rendered. The browser showed plain html text. What could be wrong?
I am new to django and trying to learn. I am clueless here and unable to understand the documentation of django.

EDIT:
I am able to get css working after following pythonvile's answers, but its still wierd.
I am able to see the effect of

```
h1, h2 {
    color: #ee3e80;}
```

but I am not able to see the effect of

```
h1 {
    background-color: rgb(238,62,128);
    color: white; }
```

or

```
body {
    background-image: url ("images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg"); }
title {
    background-color: rgb(238,62,128);
    color: white; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolute paths when defining MEDIA_ROOT, STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS and TEMPLATE_DIRS. Good practice is to start off settings module (it doesn't have to be a single file!) with something like this:

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
```

Yeah yeah, I know how it looks, the most awful piece of Python I've encountered so far. Yet it IS a way to go. Let's check it out in a shell:

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.PROJECT_DIR
Out[2]: '/home/yourname/Projects/simple_emp_hr/simple_emp_hr/..'
```

Which is equivalent to `/home/yourname/Projects/simple_emp_hr` right?
Now we can use `os.path.join` again to glue dirs together:

```
In [3]: import os

In [4]: os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_DIR, 'foo', 'bar')
Out[4]: '/home/yourname/Projects/simple_emp_hr/simple_emp_hr/../foo/bar'
```

And here we go in the actual settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static') # you will have something different, I guess
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'hr_base', 'static'),
)
```

Same drill for MEDIA_ROOT.

EDIT: my urls snippet for static. I shamelessly took it from some blog back in a day.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # normal patterns
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

Comment: Check this on my console:[18/Feb/2014 12:01:04] "GET /hr_base/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3640. It doesnt make sense

Comment: It should start with static. Its so confusing as to which directory is  accessed by which url. Can you check the url file I posted earlier and let me know if thats ok?

Comment: This gets even worse, I am dumping the html on to console for debugging. {{ STATIC_URL }} in that is getting rendered as nothing. Its literally nothing.

Comment: I needed to add the context dictionary entry for 'STATIC_URL' : settings.STATIC_URL. I have used the command python manage.py collectstatic. Then there is  proper /static/hr_base/css/base.css copied. The url in html looks ok now. But still, css is not rendered in my browser.

Comment: What about the urls in the css files? Am I suposed to use {{STATIC_URL}}/images/bla_bla_bla.jpg ?

Comment: It looks like the css file is retrieved but somehow not getting applied on the html. I am not able to make out where its going wrong.

Comment: I'm added my urls.py to the answer. You can try it, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. Are you sure you put absolute paths everywhere where required? Can you post your current `settings.py`? Append it to the question. Also, did you test things inside the shell? BTW, I recommend using `./manage.py shell_plus` which comes with `django-extensions`.

Comment: Its applying the css. But not sure why the page background is not applied

Comment: Try `"static/images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg"` or `"/static/images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg"`. `{{STATIC_URL}}` won't be rendered inside the stylesheet.

Comment: No use. Its still not rendering the background image. I have tried both the ideas you provided. /static/ as well as plain static/.
In the terminal, I see 2 GET calls. One for the html, one for the css. I think there should be one for for the image. But I don't see it.

Comment: OK, I don't know much about CSS but shouldn't it be outside quotation? `url(/static/images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg)`. Also try relative path `url(../images/foto-camion-transformers.jpg)`

Comment: Nothing works for background images. I tried with single, double as well as no quotes with and without escape characters. It doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: It works only when we use "python manage.py collectstatic". Thanks, I think I have most of the things in place now.

Comment: Glad I could help at least a little bit. There shouldn't be a need for collectstatic on dev server. Anyway, static files management in Django IS complicated, nothing wrong with being confused.

Comment: You have been a lot of help. I am glad I am getting good experts here to solve problems.

Answer (score -2):

You should be looking at using Django compressor, http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ 
.
Its totally worth the learning curve. Solves many problems

Comment: Nope. OP needs to learn how to work with the basics before looking at alternatives. Anyhow, this isn't an answer, it should be a comment